# How does the mlx5 driver use the IOVA generated by IOMMU as DMA address?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, mellanox, rdma

I have enabled `IOMMU` on the physical machine. I expect the `RDMA NIC` to use the `IOVA` allocated by the `IOMMU module` for `DMA` after enabling `IOMMU`. However, in reality, the `RDMA NIC` does not use the `IOVA` for `DMA`：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOId8.png)

I found through reading the kernel source code that `ib_dma_map_sgtable_attrs()` is called in `ib_umem_get` to obtain the `DMA address` for each `scatterlist (sg) entry`. During the process of obtaining the `DMA address`, it first checks whether `dev->ops` is empty, and then decides whether to assign the `DMA address` to `IOVA`. Currently, it was debugged that `dev->ops` is empty at this point, and the `DMA address` is not assigned to `IOVA`.

Does the mlx5 driver perform any other actions (such as assigning `dev->ops`) when obtaining the struct device *dev to be able to use `IOMMU`?